# JQuery Calculator: Calculate Input, Clear After

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

http://jsbin.com/UYusECo/1/
http://jsbin.com/UYusECo/1/edit

All the functions on the calculator work fine, but after I hit equal for say 6+6= and then my result shows to be 12. When I press 2 or any other number I want to clear the input of 12 or whatever the last calculation was and start a new calculation. 
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier way to do it, where you don't have to edit every button. Just use this as the handler for your `=` key:

```
comp.click(function () {
    Input.val(eval(Input.val()));
    $('input:button').one('click', function newOp(e) {
        if (/\d/.test(this.value)){
            Input.val(this.value);
        }
        $('input:button').off('click', newOp);
    });
});
```

Not the best way to do it, certainly, but it works.

Comment: Thank you this is the solution I was looking for. Can you explain the /\d/?

Comment: Sure! It's a regular expression that will [match a single digit.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit) The [.test() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest) checks to see if the button's value matches that expression and returns true or false. Basically, if the button you click after the `=` is a digit, reset the field.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you code, it will be a bit messy but when hitting equals set a variable to true

```
newCalc = true;
```

When catching the input `if (newCalc) {$("#clear).trigger (); newCalc = false}`